# PHP CURL GET 403 forbidding

Tags: php, curl, ubuntu-20.04

I have installed a new ubuntu server v20 with PHP Version 7.4.3 to move a web application from an older ubuntu server v18 with PHP Version 7.0 and I am getting a 403 error on the new server when performing a CURL REST API GET. Bellow is the code with the error debug, portions of the license key have been modified for the post. I haven't been able to find anything related to this searching around existing posts. Thanks for the help in advance

```
ob_start();
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://license.cmadsystems.com?lic=P9xP1o7USRLkS591cFzBbLSmI9ZTtvR7xgfr86dtYiCZuhy",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0",
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
  CURLOPT_STDERR => $out,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

fclose($out);
$debug = ob_get_clean();


echo $response;
echo $err;
echo $debug;
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access this resource.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
*   Trying 216.250.121.144:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to license.cmadsystems.com (216.250.121.144) port 80 (#0)
> GET /?lic= P9xP1o7USRLkS591cFzBbLSmI9ZTtvR7xgfr86dtYiCZuhy HTTP/1.1
Host: license.cmadsystems.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Content-Type: application/json

* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=15
< Date: Wed, 20 May 2020 23:45:29 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< 
* Connection #0 to host license.cmadsystems.com left intact
```

Comment: A licence check over HTTP in 2020? My goodness! In my browser I am getting a 200, even with your crippled licence. Can you just double check it with _file_get_contents_?

Comment: It __kind of__ works for me as well: `<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: Lic_Info in <b>/home/u264166153/domains/cmadsystems.com/public_html/license/index.php</b> on line <b>86</b><br />
{"status":200,"status_message":"Licensed","data":{"Lic_End":null,"Lic_Device":0,"Lic_MOH":0,"Lic_Info":null}}`

Comment: maybe you don't need to set `"Content-Type: application/json"`

Comment: I ran your code in my local machine, and it was working!

Answer (score 1):

In my case it this was a DNS issue. license.cmadsystems.com was resolving to the wrong IP address.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo file_get_contents(
    "http://license.cmadsystems.com?lic=P9xP1o7USRLkS591cFzBbLSmI9ZTtvR7xgfr86dtYiCZuhy"
);
```

> Returns

```
"status":200,
"status_message":"Licensed",
"data":{
        "Lic_End":null,
        "Lic_Device":0,
        "Lic_MOH":0,
        "Lic_Info":null
    }
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer since it was already stated in the comments a dozen times ;)